# I am trying to create a selenium script but got stuck when i am trying to click on a button "Save".I have given below html available

Tags: java, selenium

```
<button id="ext-gen1546" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" style="width: 69px;">

<span id="ext-gen1548" class="x-btn-inner" 

style="width: 69px;">Save</span>
<span id="ext-gen1549" class="x-btn-icon">
</span>
</button>
```

Above is HTML of this Save button.
ID is dynamic
Tried with  class but unable to find element.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am unable to locate Save button present on the page.Need to click on it after finding it to save data.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try with

> `driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));`

Comment: I have tried below script but this is not working-                                        WebElement element8 = D1.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
  element8.click();                                                                                           The page has two buttons Save and Exit.Need to identity Save and then click

Comment: Why don't you try List<WebElement> element8 = D1.findElements(By.tagName("button")); element8.get(0).click();